# No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin groups Error

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

Everything was working fine till yesterday with Jenkins and Sonar (using Maven). Suddenly I saw below error in Jenkins logs and build fails for all projects with the same error.

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/user/mysys/.m2/repository), nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/user/mysys/.m2/repository), nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

I have sonar running and sonar plugin installed in Jenkins.

What could be the issue. Can any one help me on this regard.

Comment: You must have changed something to your configuration, because this can't happen "suddenly"...

Comment: Hi Fabrice, I had set cobertura max memory(in sonar settings) to 1.5 GB to make one of our big project generate code coverage. After making cobertura memory change I see big project generates code coverage reports but all subsequent builds fail with the above error including all small projects. Could you please suggest anything here.

Answer (score 3):

I've the same problem since this morning .I didn't make any changes on my conf. I found a solution , on Jenkins : Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Sonar -> Advanced  -> Version of sonar-maven-plugin , i put 2.1 and all my projects work fine now, weird ...

Comment: Hi Bigoudenus, It worked for me as well after putting Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Sonar -> Advanced -> Version of sonar-maven-plugin as 2.1. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Same here. I've defined the plugin in pom (so we can also run sonar locally)

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these resolved it for me. I was getting the error when running in Bamboo. I didn't need to add anything to the pom. It was the JDK version I was using to run the Sonar Maven task.